# Let's remove the [jbdc] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19660488) that replaced the [jbdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbdc) tag with the [jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdbc) tag.

I looked up `jbdc` thinking it may have some obscure meaning in the programming context, but it looks like it just stands for "Jamaica Business Development Corporation".

There's only one question tagged with this at the moment, and three people follow this tag.

Let's do away with it. It's evidently a typo.

Comment: Typo'd tags will die around 2-3AM UTC. This won't be a thing soon.

Comment: @Makoto You mean that there's an automated process for removing typo'd tags? I had no idea.

Comment: There's an automated process for removing tags that aren't in use by any questions. You'd still need to remove the wrong tag, and replace it with the correct one, which someone has already done.